# How to pass msbuild properties to another msbuild script correctly?

Tags: msbuild

I have a master.proj msbuild script which builds several projects using the `MSBuild` task.

Here is a typical example:

```
<Target Name="Log4PostSharp" DependsOnTargets="log4net">
  <MSBuild Projects="Log4PostSharp\Log4PostSharp.sln" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
</Target>
```

But, my problem is that if more properties are given on the command line, they are not passed to the MSBuild task.

Is there a way to pass the MSBuild task all the properties given on the command line?

Thanks.

Comment: I asked a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260913/how-to-access-the-msbuild-command-line-parameters-from-within-the-project-file-b) -- never found a solution to this, which seems to be a serious deficiency in msbuild, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly pass your extra property as a **semicolon-delimited list of property name/value pairs** in `Properties` attribute. It's not pretty but it's the way to go :

```
<Target Name="Log4PostSharp" DependsOnTargets="log4net">
  <MSBuild Projects="Log4PostSharp\Log4PostSharp.sln" 
           Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);
                       Platform=$(Platform);
                       OtherPropertyPassInCommandLine=$(PropertyValue)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: This is not a question of pretty. It is simply impossible. Master.proj is used to build many projects at once. It just cannot know which properties are relevant to which projects.